# WooCommerce PayPal Payments Plugin doesn't show buttons on checkout page

Tags: woocommerce, plugins, paypal, payment, conflict

**Hi Team**

WooCommerce PayPal Payments Plugin isn't showing Paypal buttons on checkout page. when i open checkout page on the browser and press f12 to check the Console it shows this error in Red Color: Refused to display 'https://www.paypal.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

**Or Sometimes getting this error on Console:**
ScriptLoading.js:23
GET [https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AaIuT3tgBl06N1xLiJLrO-HCy20j_sX_aAy…sages&vault=false&commit=true&intent=capture&enable-funding=venmo,paylater](https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AaIuT3tgBl06N1xLiJLrO-HCy20j_sX_aAy%E2%80%A6sages&vault=false&commit=true&intent=capture&enable-funding=venmo,paylater) net::ERR_ABORTED 400
(anonymous) @   ScriptLoading.js:23
(anonymous) @   button.js:261

**I suspect it to be conflicting with one of these plugins or both:**
-WooCommerce Checkout Manager
-WooCommerce Price Based on Country

Both are important for my website!

Because when i desactivate them the buttons show sometimes

I have the same plugins installed on a different website that i created months ago, it's working properly!

-i have tried deleting woocommerce and all related pages and re-installing it
-Tried changing a theme to Storefront and to twenty-twenty-three and Hello Elementor
-also tried deleting checkout page and creating it again
-tried Disabling/Enabling Paypal in the plugins settings
-Tried reinstalling WooCommerce PayPal Payments Plugin

I had the same issue when i was building one of my other websites months ago, but i had deleted woocommerce back then and re-installed it again, and changed chechout template to elementor Canvas and everything got back to normal and it is still working fine on that website.

Thank you for being interesting in helping me